# VxWorks 5.5 to VxWorks 7.0 migration

Tags: c++, vxworks

We have working Vxworks 5.5 code in a Tornado environment.

Does anyone know if same code can be compiled using WindRiver Workbench 4? Or rather does WindRiver Workbench 4 support Vxworks 5.5? Assume that we have a compatible board support package for the target motherboard.

Further, on a scale of 1 - 5 (1 being easy and 5 being hard), how difficult is it to migrate C++ code developed for VxWorks version 5.5 to VxWorks version 7.0? I appreciate this is to some extent a subjective assessment, but I would like to get a feel for if we are talking total rewrite or just a few changes to OS API parameters.

Tried to compile the VxWorks project in Workbench 4 and it produced a lot of errors. Consequently wondering if this is a dead end or if it's worth working through the error log.

Comment: It is always worth if you don't have a hello world program, you learn a lot about new concepts

Comment: @nbk Unfortunately there's a LOT of code we have to port. It does quite a bit of inter-process communication using semaphores and so on and I just wondered how much the platform had changed between the two versions

Comment: you will find that the changes repeat them selves and some need some research, it is normal when changing versions.